# Jquery-Mobile: $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg() is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, jquery-mobile

I am new jquery mobile. i want to use showPageLoadingMsg() of jquery mobile.But it is not working. Following is my code please can anybody help me.

```
code

< !DOCTYPE html>   
< html> 
< head> 
    < meta charset="utf-8"> 
    < meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    < title>Single page template</title>
    < link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
    < script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    < script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
< /head> 
< body>
< !-- BMR Screen page -->

  < div data-role="page" id="BMR_screen">

  < div data-role="header" data-theme="e" id="hdrBMRScreen">

  < h1> BMR Screen< /h1>
  < /div>

  < div data-role="content" id="contentBMRScreen"> 

        < div data-role="fieldcontain">  

             < label for="BMR_age">Age(in years):</label> 

             < input type="text" id="BMR_age" /> 

        < /div> 

        < a href="#BMR_Result" onclick="BMR_Cal()"  data-role="button">submit</a> 

  < /div>

 < /div>

 < !-- End BMR Screen -->

   < div data-role="page" id="BMR_Result">

       < div data-role="header" data-theme="b" >

            < a data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-icon="back">back</a>

            <h1>BMR Result</h1> 

       < /div>

        < div data-role="content">      

          < p id="W_Range">Weight Range:</p>   

        < /div>
    < /div>

  < script type="text/javascript"> 

  var agevar;


  $(document).ready(function () {   
    // Initialize variables 
    ageVar = $('#BMR_age');     
  });

  function BMR_Cal()

 {    
    $.mobile.loadingMessage = "please wait...";     
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();

    if(ageVar.val() > 0)
    {       
        some code is there
        .............

        $.mobile.changePage( $("#BMR_Result"), { transition: "flip"} );       
    }

    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();

  }
  < /script>
  < /body> 
< /html>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because you are calling both inside the same js method, so the browser doesn't have time to update it's UI...

UPDATE: seems there were some more changes needed. Here's my simplified working version of your function:

```
function BMR_Cal(){
    $.mobile.loadingMessage = "please wait...";
    var ageVar = $('#BMR_age');

    if (ageVar.val() > 0) {
        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
        $.ajax({
            url:"http://wwww.google.com",
            complete: function(){
                $.mobile.changePage($("#BMR_Result"), {transition: "flip"});
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
}
```

Of course you'll have to replace the .ajax call to your own code.

Here's the [full working jsFiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/aW9d2/)

Comment: try with the setTimeout, as UPDATEd in my answer

Comment: still it' not working.here i am using $(document).ready function. is any problem with this? Because i saw in some where there are using $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  //apply overrides here
});

Comment: regarding the events, in jqm you should never use the document.ready event, since that will fire only the first time the page is full loaded. In your case thought, there's no need for it at all (at least from the sample code)

Comment: thanks it's working. What is the difference between ready and bind?

Comment: document.ready is fired by the browser only once while everything is loaded; the point with JQM is that it manages your hyperlinks and loads them using ajax - dynamically appending them to your current page - so the browser will never fire that .ready event. In case you need to do something on jqm page loads, you must bind to the jqm events. Here's the [full documentation on JQM events](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try it but it seems like you should prevent the default action (i.e. the automatic jump to #BMR_Result) of the anchor/button.

```
<a href="#BMR_Result" onclick="BMR_Cal(); return false;" data-role="button">submit</a>
```

Comment: I have to show/hide the loading message using showPageLoadingMsg() and hidePageLoadingMsg(). it is not working

Answer (score 0):

The $.mobile.loadingMessage = "please wait..." setting needs to be defined in the mobileinit event handler. And that handler needs to be bound exactly after you've loaded jQuery, but before you've loaded jQueryMobile.

It's still strange that it's not working for you though, as you should still be getting the default page loading text, i.e. 'loading'. Have you set $.mobile.loadingMessage to false somewhere else?

In any case, I'm doing everything by the book and I still can't get this method to do what I want.